# unable to send file and form data together from angular to node js server

Tags: node.js, angular, file-upload, httprequest, multer

***I am creating an signup page I want user to upload image at signup or he can skip it to if when is send post request from angular only file or body data come in node. I am using template driven form in angular  I want both in one request***

**http service file**``

```
import {  HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  httpOptions = {enter code here
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'appliction/JSON'
  })
}

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
 
  register(data: any , Image: string | Blob){
   let fd = new FormData();
   fd.append('file', Image)
   //fd.append('data', data)
    
 
    console.log(data)
    
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:7860/signup",{data,fd})
  }

}




**req console (body) in nodejs**




body: {
    data: {
      profileImage: 'C:\\fakepath\\pexels-photo-248797.jpeg',
      name: 'Mandeep',
      email: 'mandeepjain00@gmail.com',
      Username: 'mk',
      date: '2021-01-16',
      password: 'Mandeep@545'
    },
    fd: {} //empty ..
  },
```

Comment: I think you have to make a choice. Either only use formData “, so also for your other inputs (and remove the json header) or use only json (use filereader to create a string from your image). Also, how are you actually calling the register function and passing in the image?

Comment: i have tried that unable to append both data and file together. it only append which is provided first

Comment: I’ve done this a dozens of times. It works fine. Read my comment again..

Comment: in node console request it give this null prototype for data   =>>                                 
 body: [Object: null prototype] { data: '[object Object]' },
  route: Route {
    path: '/signup',
    stack: [ [Layer], [Layer] ],
    methods: { post: true }
  },

Answer (score 0):

**formdata unable to hold object inside object so by iterating each form control data and the append to FormData will work in this case**

**function that call when submit button click**

```
onClickSubmit(data: any){  
    const formData = new FormData(); 
    for (const property in data) {
            //console.log(`${property}: ${data[property]}`);
            formData.append(`${property}` , `${data[property]} `)
    }
    
        formData.append('image', this.image)
    this._userSignup.register(formData)
    .subscribe( 
        data => {console.log(data),this._route.navigate(['login'])},
        error => console.log(error)
    )
}
```

**user.service file**

```
    import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'appliction/JSON'
  })
}

formData : String[] = new Array

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
 
  register(formData: FormData){
   console.log(formData)
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:7860/signup",formData)
  }

}
```